# getting a result of a table Mysqli left join

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

So what i want is the following. I have 3 tables: first i will explain in english what i want for final result:

let me explain all in english:

table 1 is REGISTERED_MEMBERS

table 2 is OPEN CLASSES

table 3 i want who appplied and to which class they applied and show that in a table when date is selected from a dropdown list!

This is how it should show at the end:
[image]

1. table = razpisani_tecaji with (ID_TECAJA, DATE, STATUS, ST_ODPRTIH_MEST)
   [image]
2. table = registrirani_clani wtih (ID_TECAJNIKA,IME,PRIIMEK, EMAIL)
   [image]
3. table = prijave_na_tecaj with (ID_TECAJNIKA, ID_TECAJA, PLACILO)

[image]

now in HTML i have a dropdown list populated with dates (this works ok) from table 1.

```
    <form>
           <select name="dates" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
                 <option value="" selected="selected">Izberi datum za pregled</option>;
<?php 
               $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','viverius_education');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ID_TECAJA, DATUM FROM razpisani_tecaji");
while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
 echo "<option value='" . $row['ID_TECAJA'] . "'>" . $row['DATUM'] . "</option>";

}
?>
```

Here a ID is saved to a variable q which is then send to php via JS. This all works. Now what i would like is for user to select a date and get a results from 3. table only to show IME from linked to ID_TECAJNIKA and PLACILO linked to ID_TECAJNIKA.

THis is what i have in PHP so far:

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','viverius_education');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

$sql="SELECT razpisani_tecaji.ID_TECAJA, registrirani_clani._ID_TECAJNIKA  FROM prijave_na_tecaj
    LEFT JOIN razpisani_tecaji ON prijave_na_tecaj.ID_TECAJA = razpisani_tecaji.ID_TECAJA
     LEFT JOIN registrirani_clani ON prijave_na_tecaj.ID_TECAJNIKA = registrirani_clani.ID_TECAJNIKA";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Ime</th>
<th>Placilo</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ID_TECAJNIKA'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['PLACILO'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Pokazi tabele i reci koji ti je finalni output

Comment: I have added the images, final output i want in HTML Table to show for selected date: IME / PRIIMEK / PLACILO

Comment: Just give me the output of the one query that you wont which resulst you want to be outputed so that i can structure the query.

Comment: Is ID_TECAJA and ID_TECAJNIKA the same thing?

Comment: Try this "SELECT rt.*,rc.*,pnt.* FROM razpisani_tecaji AS rt 
INNER JOIN prijave_na_tecaj AS pnt ON rt.ID_TECAJA = pnt.ID_TECAJA
INNER JOIN registrirani_clani AS rc ON rc.ID_TECAJNIKA = rc.ID_TECAJNIKA = pnt.ID_TECAJNIKA"

Comment: let me explain all in english: 
table 1 is REGISTERED_MEMBERS
table 2 is OPEN CLASSES
table 3 i want who appplied and to which class they applied and show that in a table when date is selected from a dropdown list!

Comment: I think that i got it in the query above we might have to adapt it a bit better but might be it works.Since i dont have any data and nor the tables.

Comment: What do you need?  I have posted the images of the tables and how i want the final result to look like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153526/discussion-between-shadowflyx-and-daamidza).

Answer (score 0):

$sql="select registrirani_clani.*, prijave_na_tecaj.*,razpisani_tecaji.*
from registrirani_clani
left join prijave_na_tecaj on registrirani_clani.ID_TECAJNIKA = prijave_na_tecaj.ID_TECAJNIKA
left join razpisani_tecaji ON razpisani_tecaji.ID_TECAJA = prijave_na_tecaj.ID_TECAJA
where razpisani_tecaji.ID_TECAJA = '".$q."'";